# Change Suspending State's TimeSpan in UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm doing some processes while my app is suspending. However, the suspending time is so long for me.

Can I adjust or change the " suspending ( running in background --> suspended) " state TimeSpan?

[image: like this]

Thanks.

Comment: which time? the time you have to handle the suspension (to have more time in OnSuspending method until you call deferral.Complete()) or the time until Windows thinks it needs to suspend your app?

Comment: "time until Windows thinks it needs to suspend your app."

Comment: this can't be extended. use background task so that your app still runs in background without suspending

Comment: I understood it, thanks.